# pyspark-How to submit Spark SQL in parrallism?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

Hi I've more than 1200+ SQL queries and want to submit multiple SQL queries in parallel and store each of them into CSV files,
since python has a GIL limit, how to submit in parallel,
I've seen other demos and they are all scala-based spark app.

```
# return about 61K records
SQL = """ 
SELECT * FROM TEMP_VIEW WHERE index>=1 and index<=10;
"""
# return about 60K records
SQL2 = """ 
SELECT * FROM TEMP_VIEW WHERE index>=11 and index<=20;
"""
....
# this will use for loop to submit
```

Any suggestion will be super helpful! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

According to [Scheduling Within an Application](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#scheduling-within-an-application) you can submit from different threads. Example:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process # Process follows the API of threading.Thread

def submit_job(query):
    ...

for job in jobs:
    Process(target=submit_job, args=('query 1',)).start()
```

But keep in mind that by default, Spark’s scheduler runs jobs in `FIFO` fashion, so I think you should consider changing the scheduler into `FAIR` so you can run multiple jobs in parallel